# how to select where month in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

How to select where month in mysql and php ?

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE insert_date=MONTH($_POST['month']);
```

Type insert_date = datetime

here code for input post month:

```html
<select name="month">
<option value="" selected>Choose Month :</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">Maret</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">Mei</option>
<option value="6">Juny</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">Augustus</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">Oktober</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">Desember</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MONTH(insert_date)=$_POST['month'];
```

Comment: @silviazulinka If this is working for you, So please accept my answer.

Comment: @silviazulinka Ok, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use $_POST directly. At least use `(int) $_POST['month']`
2. If insert_date is a date or timestamp field, use `WHERE MONTH(insert_date) = :month` with :month bind as `(int) $_POST['month']`